# Storing user authentication responses with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Just getting my head round DotNetOpenAuth and need clarification on something so hope someone can advise.

Looking at the samples (OpenIdProviderWebForms) at the provider end after successful login, the user is presented with the confirmation page asking you to confirm (decide.aspx). If you click 'Yes', ideally I would like it to store this so that the next time the user does not see this page.

My question is, would this typically be something the provider would have to add into the code to store it in their own database for example? Or are there some tools, techniques or provisions already in DotNetOpenAuth to do this that I've missed. The only thing I can find around this is CustomStore.

You advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering the user's choice is something the provider should store in its database.  DotNetopenauth supports this but it does require work on your end to decide to go ahead and respond positively.